# Store data into remote database via web service in Android

Tags: android, sql, web-services, android-spinner

I have an Android code that contains 2 spinners and a TimePickerDialog. A user can select any option from each of the spinners and then set a Time. I want to store the option selected by a user and the time set in a remote database via a web service. My database would be in SQL.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution you should try is to create JSON and post it to your WebService.

For creating JSON, you need to use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) classes.

For example:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("Spinner1Value",strSpinner1Value);
obj.put("Spinner2Value",strSpinner2Value);
obj.put("DateTimeValue",strDateTime);
```

and now make a web call with this obj value.

Comment: so that means depending upon the number of spinner values I have, i will need to write those obj.put statements ..right?

Comment: @Parth_90 yes you must, if you prefer XML creation then you have to follow this.

Comment: Do you know well enough about JSON? If not then just look at this example get idea: http://goo.gl/gH7bi

Comment: no not much ..will understand it from the link u have given thnx !! :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a web service which exposes an API for interaction with mobile device. You can use PHP or Ruby on Rails for that. Plus you'll need some simple auth (http will work).

On the android side you will create a request (for example HTTP POST), publish it to the web service and check the response code.

Comment: Do I need to pass those values as parameters in HTTP POST so that it can be published to the web service? Any example u can give please

Comment: @Parth_90: The easiest way in this case you can just pass key/value pairs in the body of the POST. Or you can try to use JSON which is what most people use. Both will work for your case.

Comment: @Dr.nik: No, not at all. Those two have most "followers" and it is easy to find tutorials. Python/Django would be another alternative. .NET and Java have web services frameworks too. Whatever the original poster feels more comfortable with.

Comment: @Zepplock can you give one simple example of store data to url for Parth?

Comment: yes that would be the icing on the cake really..will make by job all the more simple..preferably an Android/JSON code would do..as my project requires that ..Thanks @Dr.nik !! :-)

Comment: Like this? http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: Thanks @Zepplock !! In the code , since at present I am working on localhost and having a database created in SQL Server 2008, what should be my URL , also what does "id", "12345" mean exactly..is it that u are passing this value all the time , because in my case I need to do need as per user input ..so then what changes should I do to that code ?

Answer (score 1):

When the user click first sppinner you can store the selected value in the global variable & take that value when call wbservice . OR create like this

```
 Spinner subject;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .....................
    HashMap<Integer, String> subjectMap = new SubjectMap<Integer, String>();
   ................ do rest of the work
    ............ Make a ArrayList & pass the value to spinner adapter
    subject = (Spinner)findById(R.id.subject);
}

public void callWbserviceMethod(){
   String selectdSubject= subjectMap .get((int) sp.getSelectedItemId());
    /// rest of the work
}
```